# React cloneElement not passing properties

Tags: reactjs, clone

In one of my projects I am trying to use a single child of my component as a "template" to render a set of products. I am cloning the child like so

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!children) {
        return;
      }
      setTemplate(React.Children.only(children));
    }, [children, setTemplate]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (loading || !products || !template) {
        return;
      }
      const rc = [];
      products.forEach((p, i) => {
        rc.push(
          React.cloneElement(template, {
            product: p,
            key: i,
          })
        );
      });
      setRenderedChildren(rc);
    }, [products, loading, template, setRenderedChildren]);
```

When I render this, the clones are created, however the properties never arrive to the underlying component.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: “The properties never are ie to the underlying component.” Can you elaborate on this more. It is unclear what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that the child component had some bugs and hence the properties defined in `cloneElement` are never assigned to my expected Component.